# Error while using sed file

Tags: command-line, sed

I have a problem while trying to run a semafore semantic parser. Among other things it uses a `sed` file to do the POS tagging and every time it comes to this I get an error message:

```
sed: Datei file:///usr/semafor-master/scripts/tokenizer.sed kann nicht geöffnet werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
(file not found).
```

The file is definitely there, I can see it and open it. `sed` function is also working, when I just try to replace some word in some text file.

What could be the problem?

Comment: sed may not understand the `file://` profile. Try removing that.

Comment: @glennjackman You may want to post an answer. Indeed `sed` does not support `file://` protocol syntax. And just with the information provided in the question, I don't think an answer that goes much beyond this is possible.

Comment: @glenn jackman thanks a lot, I knew it is as always some little thing I am missing! everything is working now!

Answer (score 3):

This question was answered in a comment:

> sed may not understand the `file://` profile. Try removing that.

– [glenn jackman](https://askubuntu.com/users/10127/glenn-jackman) [Jul 21 '17 at 10:51](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938340/error-while-using-sed-file#comment1487668_938340)

Indeed `sed` does not support `file://` protocol syntax. (Most command-line programs do not.)

Removing `file://` from the beginning changed it from a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) to a Unix-style path (`/usr/semafor-master/scripts/tokenizer.sed`), which [fixed the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938340/error-while-using-sed-file#comment1489702_938340).